# How do I clone my drive to a external USB drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk-utility

I have CarbonCopyCloner but it cannot see my new SSD in the destination section. The destination drive is a USB-attached SSD.

How do I clone to this drive in CarbonCopyCloner?

Comment: OK SO I READ OTHER RESPONSES AND IN DISK UTILITY SELECTED PARTITION THEN MADE 1 PARTITION ADDED A NAME FOR THIS SSD PARTITION AND APPLIED. THIS DID THE TRICK. NOW I CAN SEE NEW SSD IN FINDER AND CAN LOAD INDIVIDUAL FILES AND ALSO SEE IN CARBON COPY CLONER FOR FULL CLONE BACK UP. THANKS FOR EDIT Ian C.

Comment: nice response Ian C. As you see have now managed it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can clone your hard drive with CarbonCopyCloner, you need to create a partition on the drive and format it appropriately for use with your Mac. Most external drives come pre-formatted for use with Windows machines.

You can use Disk Utility for this purpose. You'll find Disk Utility under `/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility` on your machine.

In Disk Utility, look along the left hand bar for the USB-attached drive. If it has a partition on it already you'll see the drive listed, with the partition indented below the drive in the list:

[image]

Select the drive, not the partition, and then use the Erase tab on wipe the drive. You want to format the drive as `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`. You can give the drive a friendly name if you like. Once Disk Utility has wiped and formatted the drive with the appropriate file system you'll be able to use it as a clone target in CarbonCopyCloner:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IN DISK UTILITY SELECTED PARTITION THEN MADE 1 PARTITION ADDED A NAME FOR THIS SSD PARTITION AND APPLIED. THIS DID THE TRICK. NOW I CAN SEE NEW SSD IN FINDER AND CAN LOAD INDIVIDUAL FILES AND ALSO SEE IN CARBON COPY CLONER FOR FULL CLONE BACK UP.